# Azure Portal - AD Group Members only lists first 100 members

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

While using the Azure Portal website(portal.azure.com) to view Azure AD group members, the site only returns a list of the first 100 group members without any sort of prompt/button for a second page.

In my case the group contains 145 users, but as its only showing the first 100 it looks like there are people missing.

Is there a way to have it display the full list of members?
If not and this is a bug, is there a known bug tracking for this so that I can keep tabs on it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a disadvantage in Azure AD new portal(portal.azure.com) , but you could use Azure AD classic portal(https://manage.windowsazure.com) to manage the full list of members, it works well :
[image]

If you have any feedback about Azure , you could post to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

**Update**

Now the new portal has the "Load more" button which could continuously load users.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. I guess the new portal just hasn't replaced the old one yet.

Comment: @NathanNelson-Smith ,Now the new portal has the "Load more" button which could continuously load users.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that this is not a Bug but a designed behavior.  Please review [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and you'll see:

The following restrictions apply to paged requests:

- The default page size is 100. The maximum page size is 999

The only way you can do this is via an actual REST API Call and use `$top = 999` in your query. Also Azure Classical Portal is an option here, just like Nan answered as it's using pages.